# Get mobile version if present, otherwise normal file

Tags: php, performance, filter, directory

I have a function which reads the contents of a dir, lets call it `/dir/css/`.
In this dir I have a few files of which I don't know the filename of, this can be random:

```
[0] filename.css
[1] filename_mobile.css
[2] otherfile.css
[3] otherfile_mobile.css
[4] generalfile.css
[5] otherGeneralfile.css
```

I have defined an constant `IS_MOBILE_USER` which has true/false as value.

When `IS_MOBILE_USER===true` I want the files with mobile suffix, OR the files of which no mobile variant exists.

```
filename_mobile.css    <- take mobile variant instead of filename.css
otherfile_mobile.css   <- take mobile variant instead of otherfile.css
generalfile.css      <- take this, no _mobile variant present
otherGeneralfile.css <- take this, no _mobile variant present
```

Anyone who can push me in the right direction? Doesnt need to be written in code, im looking for a train of though (but code is perfectly acceptable :P)

Edit: Performance is important, otherwise I'd make a function which loops through the array a few times to make sure everything matches. But arrays are slow :)

---

This is where I'm at now, this gives me an array with everything without `_mobile` files. Now I want to add some code that gives me the `_mobile` variant if possible, without having to loop through it again.

```
define('IS_MOBILE_USER', true); // true now, I use this to test, could be false
function scandir4resource($loc, $ext){
    $files = array();
    $dir = opendir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$loc);
    while(($currentFile = readdir($dir)) !== false){
        // . and .. not needed
        if ( $currentFile == '.' || $currentFile == '..' ){
            continue;
        }
        // Dont open backup files
        elseif( strpos($currentFile, 'bak')!==false){
            continue;
        }
        // If not mobile, and mobile file -> skip
        elseif( !IS_MOBILE_USER && strpos($currentFile, '_mobile')!==false){
            continue;
        }
        // if mobile, current file doesnt have '_mobile' but one does exist->skip
        elseif( IS_MOBILE_USER && strpos($currentFile, '_mobile')===false 
                && file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$loc.str_replace(".".$ext, "_mobile.".$ext, $currentFile)) ){
            continue;
        }
        // If survived the checks, add to array:
        $files[] = $currentFile;
    }
    closedir($dir);
    return $files;
}
```

I have this is a small benchmark, 10.000 calls to this function takes 1.2-1.5sec, looping again would take allot of time.

```
for($i=0; $i<=10000; $i++){
    $files = scandir4resource($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."UserFiles/troep/");
}
```

At the end this is the result:
"Took 1.8013050556183 seconds" and stays arround that value
The difference between `is_file` and `file_exists` is very minimal, I prefer file_exists in this syntax because im checking if it exists, not if it is a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$filesArray = glob("/path/to/folder/*.css");
foreach($filesArray as $index => $file) {
   if( stripos($file,"_mobile") !== FALSE || 
       !in_array( str_replace(".css","_mobile.css",$file), $filesArray ) )
     continue;
   unset($filesArray[$index]);
}
```

Grabs all the css files, unsets any that do not have "_mobile" but keeps the ones that do not have a mobile alternative.

**Edit to work with your current loop**

```
if ( $currentFile == '.' || $currentFile == '..' ) continue;

$isMobile = stripos($currentFile,"_mobile") !== FALSE;
$hasMobileVer = is_file($loc.str_replace(".css","_mobile.css",$currentFile));

if (           
      ( IS_MOBILE_USER && (  $isMobile || !$hasMobileVer )  ) ||
      ( !IS_MOBILE_USER && !$isMobile ) 
   )
   $files[] = $currentFile;
```

when `IS_MOBILE_USER` is true, it checks if it has `_mobile` or if a `_mobile` version doesn't exist, if so it adds it to the array.
If IS_MOBILE_USER is false it just checkes if `_mobile` is not present and if so adds it to the array.

Comment: That will get me the mobile files, but not the general files

Comment: Well you can use that that check that mobile files exist

Comment: Your edit is a bit odd. The glob selects all `_mobile` files and than you check with stripos if the name containts `_mobile`. Im gonna think about a part of your solution to see whan I can do

Comment: forgot to take out the _mobile in the glob selector

Comment: I've added my own function to the topic, your current code will not work in what I have, because $files isnt yet filled. Thanks for the effort so far though

Comment: added an if statement that uses `is_file` to check for `_mobile` version, should make it so you dont need to do another loop.

Comment: I didnt think of the `is_file()` function, that could help allow. Thanks